# How to elegantly detect when all Promises are rejected?

Tags: javascript, promise

How can I execute a function **when all Promises have been rejected**? I think Promise.all isn't suited, unless I reject the promises instead of resolving them. But it would not be logical to do that in my situation, and thus make the code trickier to follow. I would like to use a similar syntax as promise.all. Since I find that sort of syntax very easy to follow.

```js
// some promises to play with
let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(resolve, 100)});

let promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(resolve, 100)});

let promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(resolve, 100)});

let promise4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(reject, 100)});

let promise5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(reject, 100)});

// run code (on .then) if all promises are resolved
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
  .then(() => console.log('1: all promises have been resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('1: one or more promises have been rejected'));

// run code (on .catch) if one or more promises are rejected
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise4])
  .then(() => console.log('2: all promises have been resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('2: one or more promises have been rejected'));

// the issue:
// run code if one or more promises are resolved
//
// How can I execute a function when all 
// promises have been rejected?
// I think Promise.all isn't 
// suited, unless I reject the promises instead of 
// resolving them. But it would not be logical to do 
// that in my situation, 
// and thus make the code trickier to follow
// I would like to use a similar syntax
// as promise.all.

// these promises should return '3: one or more promises have been resolved' and '4: all promises have been rejected'
Promise.all([promise2, promise4])
  .then(() => console.log('3: one or more promises have been resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('3: all promises have been rejected'));
  
  Promise.all([promise5, promise4])
  .then(() => console.log('4: one or more promises have been resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('4: all promises have been rejected'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[promise1, promise2, promise3 /*...*/]
 .reduce((chain, promise) => chain.catch(() => promise))
 .catch(() => console.error("all failed"));
```

This builds up a promise chain.

Comment: When a Promise is resolved after a previous Promise from the Array has been rejected, Google Chrome throws this error message: `Uncaught (in promise)`. This occurs for example in an array like [promise4, promise3]. Any idea what is going on there?

Comment: @RMo you should add a proper error handler to every promise, e.g. `promise3.catch(console.error)`. The chain does no real errorhandling

Answer (score 0):

Try promise-any npm module or bluebird's equivalent. You can stop when at least one promise has been resolved, or fail if non resolved:

```
Promise.any([....])
.then(() => "bad, at least one resolved"), () => "good, all rejected")
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you correctly you want to run a function **if and only if when all** promises are rejected and you want something as elegant as `Promise.all()` right..? Then you can still use `Promise.all()` but you need a little helper function to `invert` the promises.

```
var invert = pr => pr.then(v => Promise.reject(v), x => Promise.resolve(x));
```

Now your three rejecting promises will do what you want.

```js
var promises = [new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(reject, 100, "1st promise rejected")}),
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(reject, 100, "2nd promise rejected")}),
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(reject, 100, "3rd promise rejected")})],
    invert   = pr => pr.then(v => Promise.reject(v), x => Promise.resolve(x));

Promise.all(promises.map(invert))
       .then(errs => errs.forEach(err => console.log(err)));
```

Oh if any of your promises resolves by some means then you may catch the resolution at the `catch` stage if you like.